# Do all global fields have infinitely many principal prime ideals?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a [global field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_field), does $K$ have infinitely many principal prime ideals? By a principal prime ideal I mean a finite place $\mathfrak{p}$ for which there exists a $p \in K$ with $\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation $1$ and $\mathfrak{q}$-adic valuation $0$ for every finite place $\mathfrak{q}$ different from $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from Chebotarev density applied to the Hilbert class field?

Comment: Possibly for number fields, although my class field theory background is too limited to fill in the details. What about global fields of odd characteristic?